# Error while running bash script that moves files

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I am new to bash script and want to create bash script that moves some days old files between source and destination as per days defined in script.

When I run this script I get error

find: paths must precede expression: mv
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Your Source Directory"
read soure

echo "Enter Your Destination Directory"
read destination 

echo "Enter Days"
read days




   find $soure -mtime +$days  mv $soure $destination {} \;

  echo "Files $days old moved from $soure to $destination"
```

What's missing or wrong ????
please help me to create this script.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this `do`-`done` pair? I don't see any `while` or `for` loop definition. I think it will work fine without these two lines. I also suggest you to start reading on basic Bash scripting.

Comment: I think I don't need it in this script

Comment: Don't change your question completely - ask a new one instead. Your original question was about a do/done syntax error, now you have problems in the `find` command.

Comment: ok sorry friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, you don't want the two `do` and `done` lines in your file. Just remove them.

Usually, they're used in `for` and `while` loops, but I don't see any of them in your script and I think you don't need them.

update (your question has become a completely new one!)

The find command lacks the `-exec` option to the command you want to run. Additionally, if you want to move files into a new destination, use `find` like this:

```
find $soure -mtime +$days -exec mv {} $destination \;
```

The `{}` already match your source files.

Comment: Now  I am getting following error find: paths must precede expression: mv
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]